# Proper change of a mongoDB

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, parse-server, database

For about a year now, I've been running a social iOS app on a parse server with thousands of users. All my data are stored in a MongoDB. The thing is, the structure of my database has to be improved. For example, the current "Following" system has to be changed in a way that it is gonna be completely different.

My question is, what is the best practise of making that change, considering that not all of my users are going to do the update? How can I be sure that there will be no confusion with the data between the old and the new users?

**Edit:**

Current Following system:
Here, every time I follow someone, I find the "user" and I append my userId, to his "followers" array...

```
|objectId <String>| -- |createdAt <Date>| -- |user <Pointer _User>| -- |followers <Array>|
```

New Following system:
Here, every time I follow someone, I create a new object, where "following" is the current user and "follower", is the user I just followed...

```
|objectId <String>| -- |createdAt <Date>| -- |following <Pointer _User>| -- |follower <Pointer _User>|
```

Comment: You might have to share a little more details than this to get a good response. Maybe consider sharing a small part of your current schema as an example, as well as you're going to change that part.

Comment: @TravisGriggs Please check my edited question...

Comment: Can you just run two mongodb collections? One with the old schema and one with the newer one?

Comment: Or use one collection, but detect the two different types. Since mongodb documents can each be different.